# How to design a graph without cycles? neo4j

Tags: graph, neo4j

I'm trying to build a graphs of people that appears in a series of books.
So person a appears in Book 1,2,3 then person b appears in Book 1,3,6.
Then I have to put an action that person a does to person b, like :person a hits person b in book 1

I know that I can put an attribute to the relationship referring to the book in what person a hits person b, but I wonder if there is a better solution..
Thanks!

Comment: what is your concern(s) on doing your data model?

Comment: I would advise you start by attempting to sketch out your graph model, on paper is fine, and share what you come up with, that would help us, help you.  even just a list of nodes (e.g. person, book) and relationships (person-[:MENTIONED_IN]->book, person-[:HIT]->person, etc)  In modeling there is rarely a right answer, but there are "more optimal' models for specific uses (e.g. answering specific questions).  There are many ways to model this...  What questions do you want to ask of the graph, after it is built?

Answer (score 0):

I'd be tempted to treat this as a versioned graph! Here's a [blog post on versioning](https://medium.com/neo4j/keeping-track-of-graph-changes-using-temporal-versioning-3b0f854536fa).

And here's an example modelled out in [Arrows.App](https://arrows.app/#/import/json=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). Of course, there could be other ways to do it too